# EF with Azure - What would be the recomended way to handle transactions?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Basically what I need is to to call DbContext.SaveChanges a few times and at the end, commit the transaction or rollback. 
It is an MVC application based on .NET 4.5 and EF 5 hosted on Windows Azure.

**-- EDITED --**

I found out TransactionScope works well in Windows Azure as long as you only have a single connection (lightweight transaction).

The exception I was getting was due to the fact that I was using DbContext and A Membership Provider inside the same transaction.

[I started a new post with more details and code here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321659/wrapping-membership-provider-and-dbcontext-on-single-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using a TransactionScope:

[TransactionScope Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

[Simple way of using transactions in ADO.NET Entity framework](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1690-simple-way-of-using-transactions-in-adonet-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: The sample code on the blog is actually how I normally do it however I don't think it works on Windows Azure / SQl Azure.

Comment: We use TransactionScope on SQL Azure just fine. However, we don't do cross-database transactions - all our transactions are on the same connection. I don't know what your scenario is...

Comment: After your comment about cross database transactions you made me think of something, I double check the project and found out that in fact TransactionScope does work. I believe my problem is that i have a dbcontext and a membership provider inside the same transaction.

Comment: You don't specify any of that in your question - you just ask a general query of 'how to do x', not that you are already trying and failing. You should flesh out your question with code and what exactly goes wrong, or close it.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. I started the question as a simple "how to question" because I though that it was different on Windows Azure. Anyways, how can I close the question? Didn't find an option for that yet.