# Wrapping membership provider and dbcontext on single transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

MVC Project using EF 5 code first and .NET 4.5.

I was looking for a way to wrap dbContext and SimpleMembershipProvider on a single transaction. I tried to use TransactionScope but since the membership provider will open another connection I get an exception (MSDTC on server 'servername' is unavailable).

So I though I could use ObjectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction instead.
The membership provider won't be part of the transaction but the idea is to have it somewhere where if it fails the transaction won't be committed.

```
Book bk1 = default(Book);
Book bk2 = default(Book);

object obc = (IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext;

obc.ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
using (tx == obc.ObjectContext.Connection.BeginTransaction) {

    bk1 = new Book {
        Name = "Book 1 Name",
        Location = "USA"
    };
    dbContext.Books.Add(bk1);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    bk2 = new Book {
        Name = "Book 2 Name. Book one Id is: " + bk1.Id,
        Location = "USA"
    };
    dbContext.Books.Add(bk2);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // this is not part of the transaction, 
    // however if it trhows an exception the transaction is aborted.
    // I'm assuming that if we got here, the commit won't fail...    
    // But is it really true?
    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("username", "123456");

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Anyways, based on the above code:

- If WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount fails, the whole thing fails, which is expected.
- If any of the SaveChanges method fails, once again the whole thing fails because we dont get to the point where CreateUserAndAccount is executed.

This whole thing bring me to a question:
Is it safe? What I mean is:

Is there any possibility the "Commit" method will throw an exception(of fail somehow) after we successfully execute DbContext.SaveChanges ? If it happens we will endup with an orphan user because the provider is not part of the transaction.

I appreciate any comments or advice on this.

*Quick note: 
There is this nice article explaining why I have to cast dbContext to IObjectContextadapter instead of using its own connection property but I can't find it anymore.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Commit` can certainly throw. One trivial example is if the connection drops. There are other cases, of course.

You have a few choices:

- Transactions on the same DB won't escalate to distributed if the connection is shared. So you could use one connection for both EF and your `WebSecurity` connection.
- Start the distributed transaction controller on the server and live with the escalation. Not the worst thing in the world.
- Instead of using a transaction, change the order of operations such that a partially successful operation can be completed or undone later. E.g., detect and clean up "orphan" users.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it possible to share the connection between EF and SimpleMembershipProvider ? I looked for a way to accomplish that before posting the question but couldn't find any.  As for the other choices: I don't think I can use Distributed Transaction with SQL Azure so I'm trying to be prepared for that.

Comment: Well, you can certainly pass an open connection to `new EntityConnection` and then pass that to the context constructor. I don't know for certain if you can extract the connection from `SimpleMembershipProvider` (or pass one), but it *seems* like there should be a way.

Comment: that would be the perfect solution but unfortunately I can't find a way to extract or pass a connection to SimpleMembershipProvider, I'm starting to believe it is not possible.

Comment: I think it's probably possible, though it may be a bit of work. `SimpleMembershipProvider` will work with any `MembershipProvider` using the [overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538008(v=vs.111).aspx). You can [supply a totally custom provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600939/how-to-make-sql-membership-provider-and-entity-framework-work-using-my-database). But if that's too much work, consider one of the other options, such as making your code resilient to "orphans" and reusing/cleaning them up later.

Comment: @CodeMaster2008: You may find [this post](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/23/perils-of-the-mvc4-accountcontroller.aspx) of interest.